# Where do I put the missing "}"?

Tags: json, json-ld

I'm am trying to add some structured data, but I keep getting an error in [Google's SDTT](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool?hl=en):

> Missing '}' or object member name.

JSON-LD:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
   "@context": "http://schema.org",
   "@type": "ProfessionalService",
   "name": "Authentic Recruitment",
   "description": "Recruitment Consultants",
   "url": "authenticrecruitment.co.uk",
   "location": 
       {
       "@type": "Place",
           "address": 
               {
               "@type": "PostalAddress",
               "addressLocality": "Sheffield",
               "addressRegion": "South Yorkshire"
               },
       },

}
</script>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: use e.g. https://jsonlint.com/  and remove the last two commas

Answer (score 0):

In objects, the `,` separates "a value from a following name" ([RFC 4627, section 2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627.html#section-2.2)).

If no name follows, the comma must not be used.

So instead of

```json
{
  "name": "…",
  "description": "…",
}
```

it has to be

```json
{
  "name": "…",
  "description": "…"
}
```

(For your example, it means that the last two commas have to be removed.)